# DST check on a locally constructed date object from millis in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone-offset

My Server is located in **ET** timezone

Client can be from any part of the world mostly *ET* or *IST*(India). My client side script manipulates the dates as follows:

```
new Date(serverTimeMillis).add("s", (localoffset+serveroffset) * 60 * 60).getTime()
```

here *localoffset* & *serveroffset* are in hours. I need to add offset here, as the *serverTimeMillis* contains the converted( ET -> Client TimeZone) time.

This is working great unless I deal with a date with EST. At present serveroffset(EDT) is -4 where a a date of EST(eg: 11/30/2013) is passed, then the *serverTimeMillis* is calculated with EST offset i.e., -5 hours and sent to client. This causes miscalculation of time about 1 hour.

I'm thinking of a way to check *serverTimeMillis* falls in EST or EDT and based on that I'll adjust my *serveroffset* for calculation.

Looks like there is no straight way to do this. Please guide me !!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In simple words I need a function which checks _serverTimeMillis_ timezone and returns _EDT_ or _EST_

Comment: After wasting quite a number of valuable hours, I found this plugin [link](https://github.com/hwki/jQuery-Timezone), and modified it to suit my requirement. But this plugin is calculating Daylight saving according to Brazil. I want to calculate for New York.

Comment: I interpreted it wrong, It isn't either Brazil or NewYork, It started interpreting based on current date. I modified the plug-in more and get it working as per my requirement. But it still has a catch. It didn't work for one hour at the start & end of the DST dates